# Need to build MS Teams bot to show a survey with buttons

Tags: node.js, bots, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, proactive-message

I need to create an MS Teams bot which would once a day send a survey in a form of a message (probably in as *adaptive cards*) to a channel (that would proabably be *proactive message*). Also, I need to be able to react to users clicking buttons and updating previously sent adaptive card. I want to build this in NodeJs (I am not sure if something like ReactJS is needed).

I was able to pull this off easily in Slack when I was building the same bot there, but I'm overwhelmed by the documentation for MS Teams solution and I've no idea where to start from: whether I should be using connector, bot, or something else. There is a bunch of examples, but none of them match exactly what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: Please refer below [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/samples/app-templates#app-template-code-samples) and check if it matches your needs. 1.https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-askaway   2.https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-hrsupport

Comment: Thanks for the links, the second one is done in c# (which I don't know). The first one I don't even know how to set up - there are some params which I don't know how to get like ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey for example.

Comment: Azure Application Insights Key used to write bot analytics data.You can get `ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey` from Configuration panel of your bot in Azure Portal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQXF7.png   
 Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-app-insights-keys?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: One more question - ist this Ask away app working in a tab, or is it posting messages (adaptive cards) straight into channels? Because I need the latter one.

Comment: From local setup wiki:
_Application insights -> Copy and store Instrumentation Key from Overview section of application insight resource._
There is nothing that goes by the name of _Instrumentation Key_
https://ibb.co/YXb8xb8

Comment: Ask Away is a Microsoft Teams bot that enables users to conduct Question and Answer, called Q&A sessions within Teams. Using the Ask Away bot, team members can submit and up-vote questions shared by colleagues allowing Q&A hosts to easily gather top-of-mind questions within a channel or chat. The bot is used to conduct a real-time Q&A session in a Teams meeting and allows attendees to submit questions live through chat.

Comment: You can get ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey from Configuration panel of your bot in Azure Portal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f12k.png